# AttributeError at /share/4 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I am tring to sent email with django using gmail smtp server i write settings in **setting.py**.here is my other code but I am getting AttributeError at /share/4 'str' object has no attribute 'get' ? please help me to solve that error.

```
**forms.py**

from django import forms 

class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    to = forms.EmailField()
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
```

**views.py**

```
def share_email(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    sent = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailPostForm(data=request.method)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post_url = 
            request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = '{} ({}) recommend you reading "{}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title)
            message = 'Read "{}" at {}\n\n{}\'s comments: {}'.format(post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comment'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@gmail.com', cd['to'])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/share_post.html', {'post': post, 'form': form, 'sent': sent})
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [path('share/<int:id>', views.share_email, name='share_post'),]
```

**share_post.html**

```
 {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
    {% block title %}
     Share Post
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% if sent %}
        <h2>E-mail successfully sent</h2>
        <p>{{ post.title }} is successfully dent by email</p>
    {% else %}
        <h2>Share {{ post.title }} by email</h2>
        <form action="{% url 'blog:share_post' post.id %}" method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Send Email">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you add all traceback ?

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
form = EmailPostForm(data=request.method)
```

you want `request.POST`, not `request.method`.

As a side note: [a successful post should be followed by a redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (to prevent page reload to repost the same data). You can use the [`contrib.messages` app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) to set a message in session, that will then be displayed on the next page.